# Is there a fee when reapplying for a Tier 2 UK visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

I (from India) have applied for a UK visa (Tier 2 Gen) and was refused due to lack of English language test. Now, I have the proper document and I want to reapply for the same visa again. I want to know if my earlier visa fee can be used for the new application.

Answer (score 3):

No, your earlier fee was for your earlier application, whether it was successful or not (the fee is not conditional on a successful application, it is a processing fee) - any new application is unrelated to your earlier application and will incur a brand new fee.

[Applying for a UK visa - Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/614897/UK_Visa_FAQ_South_Africa_PPA_May_2017.pdf)

> **My application was refused how do I get a refund?**
>
> - Visa fees won’t be refunded if the application is refused, this fee does not guarantee a visa
>     but covers the decision-making process.